# Mist ctrl + F5 equivalent

Tags: mist

In Mist browser is there an equivalent to ctrl + F5 in other browsers (clear cache and reload all sources)?

I understand it is a fork of Chromium but F5 does not even perform a refresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is, although it's a little bit hacky.
Open Developer Tools (Develop > Developer Tools > Mist UI), then head to Network tab and mark this checkbox:

[image]

So every time you hit Cmd + R or F5, while Developer Tools window is open, it'll perform a hard refresh.